# what is Ljava.lang.String;@

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string array `selectCancel` with setter and getter methods, which is a checkbox in my form. I am trying to get the checked values and I am getting the above result when I print.

I tried the `Arrays.toString()` method but it still prints the same.

I then did the following:

```
String checked = Arrays.toString(Employee.getSelectCancel());
```

I also tried with the `Arrays.asList()` and `Arrays.copyOf()`

So, how do I read this string?

Comment: An *array* with *getter/setter* which is a *checkbox*? #lost

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The method *works* if you provide an array. The output of

```
String[] helloWorld = {"Hello", "World"};
System.out.println(helloWorld);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(helloWorld));
```

is

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@45a877
[Hello, World]
```

(the number after `@` is almost always different)

*Please tell us the return type of `Employee.getSelectCancel()`*

Answer (score 31):

`Ljava.lang.String;@` is returned where you used string arrays as strings. `Employee.getSelectCancel()` does not seem to return a `String[]`

Comment: Once the string array is sorted with Arrays.sort(a); convert it into strings by using Arrays.toString(a) and then print it. Whole code will look like this:

import java.util.Arrays;
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
        
        String [] a = { "ew" , "ds" , "as" };
        
        Arrays.sort(a);
        System.out.println (Arrays.toString(a));
        
        
    }
}

Answer (score 13):

According to the Java Virtual Machine Specification (Java SE 8), [JVM §4.3.2. Field Descriptors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2):

> ```
> FieldType term | Type      | Interpretation
> -------------- | --------- | --------------
> L ClassName ;  | reference | an instance of class ClassName
> [              | reference | one array dimension
> ...            | ...       | ...
> ```

the expression `[Ljava.lang.String;@45a877` means this is an array ( `[` ) of class java.lang.String ( `Ljava.lang.String;` ). And `@45a877` is the address where the String object is stored in memory.

Answer (score 12):

`[` stands for single dimension array 
`Ljava.lang.String` stands for the string class (L followed by class/interface name)

Few Examples:

1. `Class.forName("[D")` -> Array of primitive double
2. `Class.forName("[[Ljava.lang.String")` -> Two dimensional array of strings.

***List of notations:*** 
**Element Type : Notation** 
boolean : Z 
byte : B 
char : C 
class or interface : Lclassname 
double : D 
float : F 
int : I 
long : J 
short : S

Answer (score 1):

I have the same trouble:
I make my own methods:
So if I gonna call method like this:

`Show("Additional String like this:"+ MyArray);//wrong command`

have error!
It's must be without "Additional String like this:"
just do like this:

`Show(AnyArray);//right command`

```
package j;

class J{
public static String [] AnyArray = new String[3];

public static void main(String[] args) {

AnyArray[0]="String_0";
AnyArray[1]="String_1";
AnyArray[2]="String_2";

/******************************************************/
Show(AnyArray); //right
/*****************************************************/
Show("Additional String like this"+AnyArray);//wrong
/****************************************************/
}


public static void Show(String[] MyArray)
{
for(int i=0;i<=MyArray.length-1;i++){
System.out.println("MyArray ["+i+"]: "+MyArray[i]+"");
 }
}



public static void Show(String MyString)
{
System.out.println(MyString);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem when I've made ListView for android app:

```
Map<String, Object> m;

for(int i=0; i < dates.length; i++){
    m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m.put(ATTR_DATES, dates[i]);
    m.put(ATTR_SQUATS, squats[i]);
    m.put(ATTR_BP, benchpress[i]);
    m.put(ATTR_ROW, row[i]);
    data.add(m);
}
```

The problem was that I've forgotten to use the `[i]` index inside the loop