# Method to retrieve value from Hashmap

Tags: java

I am facing problem in getting value from hashmap

```
Map<String, Object> mapObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String[] strArray = {"String1", "String2"};
mapObj.put("string_array",strArray);

//trying to print:
for (String entry : mapObj.keySet()) {
    Log.v("", "map entry "+ entry);
    Log.v("", "map value "+ mapObj.get(entry));
}
```

actual output: [Ljava.lang.String;@410ee550

expected : String1 String2

Answer (score 2):

Array types don't override [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) so what you see is the super class representation

> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

of the array object itself. You could do

```
System.out.println("map value "+ Arrays.toString((String[])mapObj.get(entry)));
```

Note: better to use a `Map<String, String[]>` in place of the original collection type to avoid casting.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an array Object.  You should iterate over that object to get elements in it.

```
for (String entry : mapObj.keySet()) {
        String[] arr = (String[]) mapObj.get(entry);
        for (String string : arr) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need typecaste here

```
for (String entry : mapObj.keySet()) {
    Log.v("", "map entry "+ entry);
    Log.v("", "map value "+ mapObj.get(entry));
  String[] strArray = (String[])mapObj.get(entry);

 //now iterate strArray 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you added `String[]` into the map so you will get `String[]`from the map. 
Therefore you need to cast the retrieved object.
`(String[])mapObj.get(entry);`

Your actual output clearly suggest that Map returned an `String[]`. See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868482/what-is-ljava-lang-string) for explanation about `[Ljava.lang.String;`

Since String[] don't override toString(), hence you need to fetch each element in array like:

```
String[] arr = (String[])mapObj.get(entry);
for(String eachString: arr){
  System.out.print(eachString);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't change the output because arrays don't override `Object#toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple you can use Arrays.toString method

```
public class MapValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> mapObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String[] strArray = {"String1", "String2"};
        mapObj.put("string_array",strArray);

        //trying to print:
        for (String entry : mapObj.keySet()) {
            Log.v("", "map entry "+ entry);
            Log.v("", "map value "+ Arrays.toString((Object[]) mapObj.get(entry)));
        }

    }

}
```